# In SQL Server, finding in a string record with 7 but not 17, but could have both

Tags: sql, sql-server

The title may not seem to make sense, but I've been trying to get something to work here, but I must be missing a trick. To explain...

For example, take these records containing the strings:

```
(1) 7 bla bla bla 17 bla bla 9 bla
(2) Bla 12 bla bla 7 bla bla bla 54 bla bla
(3) Bla bla bla 6 bla bla 17 bla bla bla 2 bla
```

So, I need to find records, using the example above, which have the value of 7 anywhere in the string. If I use a ...LIKE '%7%'... it finds records 1, 2 and 3, but I only want it to find records with 7 (and not just 17), so it should only find records 1 and 2.

Obviously, if I add ...NOT LIKE '%17%'... then I only get record 2 so that doesn't help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should probably be storing these values in a junction table, rather than in delimited lists.

However, you can do what you want using `like`:

```
where ' ' + col + ' ' like '% 7 %'
```

That is, add delimiters to the beginning and end of the string and then use them in the pattern to match.

Comment: That's it. I knew it had to be a simple answer, but I just couldn't see it. Much appreciated, thanks.

Comment: That won't find record (1) in the example - you need '7 %' or '% 7 %'

Comment: @snow_FFFFFF . . . I don't think you understand the answer.

Answer (score 0):

What about this - (include some spaces to exclude other values that include 7)

```
LIKE '7 %' OR LIKE '% 7 %'
```

Answer (score 0):

How about a mix:

```
Like '7 %' or Like '% 7' or Like '% 7 %'
```